# Can't get the Post Generated Key from the Firebase to add Comment inside the child

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hey guys iam trying to build a Social Media Application useing Firebase Realtime Database

but am Stuck in how to get the `posts generated key`  to add the Comments inside it so  how to get the push key generated to the post  and how to show the comment inside the Clicked Post

Database Structure

[image]

> Here is the Activity that Shows the Post Details When i click on the post in Recyclerview it Intents me to this Activity

```
    public class ShowThePost extends AppCompatActivity {


        Dialog dialog;
        FirebaseUser mAuth;
        DatabaseReference dbRef;
        Intent intent;

        @BindView(R.id.imgPostShow) PhotoView PostImage;
        @BindView(R.id.Show_profile_image) CircularImageView UserProfilePicture;
        @BindView(R.id.postTitleShow) TextView PostTitle;
        @BindView(R.id.txt_Show_UserName) TextView UserProfileName;
        @BindView(R.id.txt_Post_Date) TextView PostDateTime;
        @BindView(R.id.Show_price) TextView RealPrice;
        @BindView(R.id.txtShowDescription) TextView PostDescription;


        @BindView(R.id.fabComment) com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton floatingActionsMenu;




        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_the_post);
            ButterKnife.bind(this);
            dialog = new Dialog(this);

            intent = getIntent();
                getDataFromIntent();
        }


        public void getDataFromIntent(){

            String id = intent.getStringExtra("post_ID");
            String title = intent.getStringExtra("post_Title");
            String description = intent.getStringExtra("post_Desc");
            String image = intent.getStringExtra("post_Image");
            String dateTime = intent.getStringExtra("post_DateTime");
            String price = intent.getStringExtra("post_Price");
            String currency = intent.getStringExtra("post_Currency");
            String UserName = intent.getStringExtra("post_UserName");
            String UserProfilePic = intent.getStringExtra("post_UserProfilePicture");



            GlideApp.with(this)
                    .load(image)
                    .into(PostImage);

            GlideApp.with(this)
                    .load(UserProfilePic)
                    .into(UserProfilePicture);

            PostTitle.setText(title);
            UserProfileName.setText(UserName);
            PostDescription.setText(description);
            RealPrice.setText(price + " : " + currency);
            PostDateTime.setText(dateTime);

        }

        public void ShowCommentDialog() {

    //        final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    //        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.create_comment,null);
    //        alert.setCancelable(false);

            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.create_comment);
        final  EditText  txtSuggestprice = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.priceSuggested);
          final EditText txtNotes = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtnotes);
            final Button btnDone = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnCommentDone);
            final Button  btnClose = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnClose);



            btnDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    final String category = intent.getStringExtra("category");
    //                 String Notes = txtNotes.getText().toString();
    //                 String SuggestedPrice =
 // 
 txtSuggestprice.getText().toString();
    //                 String UserID = mAuth.getUid().toString();
    //                 String UserProfilePic = mAuth.getPhotoUrl().toString();
    //                 String UserName = mAuth.getDisplayName().toString();
    //
    //                CommentsList commentsList = new CommentsList();
    //                commentsList.setUserID(UserID);
    //                commentsList.setUserProfilePicture(UserProfilePic);
    //                commentsList.setCommentDescription(Notes);
    //                commentsList.setCommentSuggestPrice(SuggestedPrice);
    //                commentsList.setCommentDate("date");
    //
                    dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");

                    Toast.makeText(ShowThePost.this, dbRef.child(category).push().getKey().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }
            });

            btnClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Toasty.info(ShowThePost.this, "Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });


            dialog.setCancelable(false);
           dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            dialog.show();

         }

         @OnClick(R.id.fabComment)
        public void OpenDialog(){
             ShowCommentDialog();
         }

    }
```

> and this is the Adapter used to send the data to the Recyclerview and Get the putExtra

```
 public class BooksAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BooksAdapter.BooksItemsHolder> {

    public BooksAdapter(List<BooksLists> listy, Context mContext) {
        this.listy = listy;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    public List<BooksLists> listy ;
    Context mContext;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public BooksItemsHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_item,parent,false);
        BooksItemsHolder holder = new BooksItemsHolder(v);
        return holder;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final BooksItemsHolder holder, int position) {

        final BooksLists list = listy.get(position);

        holder.PostTitle.setText(list.getPost_title());
        holder.PostDate.setText(list.getPost_datetime());

        GlideApp.with(mContext)
                .load(list.getPost_image())
                .into(holder.imgPostCover);



        holder.UserProfileName.setText(list.getUser_name());

        GlideApp.with(mContext)
                .load(list.getUser_pp())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.user)
                .into(holder.TheUserProfilePic);

        holder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,ShowThePost.class);

                intent.putExtra("post_ID",list.getPost_id());
                intent.putExtra("post_Title",list.getPost_title());
                intent.putExtra("post_Desc",list.getPost_description());
                intent.putExtra("post_Image",list.getPost_image());
                intent.putExtra("post_DateTime",list.getPost_datetime());
                intent.putExtra("post_Price",list.getPost_real_price());
                intent.putExtra("post_Currency",list.getCurrency());
                intent.putExtra("post_UserName",list.getUser_name());
                intent.putExtra("post_UserProfilePicture",list.getUser_pp());
                intent.putExtra("category",list.getCategory());


                mContext.startActivity(intent);


            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listy.size();
    }

    public class BooksItemsHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        @BindView(R.id.TheuserProfilePicture)
        CircularImageView TheUserProfilePic;
        @BindView(R.id.userName) TextView  UserProfileName;
        @BindView(R.id.imgPostShow) ImageView imgPostCover;
        @BindView(R.id.postTitle) TextView PostTitle;
        @BindView(R.id.txt_Post_Date) TextView PostDate;
        @BindView(R.id.GotoPostItem)
        CardView linearLayout;
        public BooksItemsHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this,itemView);


        }
    }


}
```

> List of the Comments.class

```
    public class CommentsList {



    public CommentsList() {
    }

    String userID;
    String userName;
    String userProfilePicture;
    String commentDate;
    String commentSuggestPrice;
    String CommentDescription;

    public String getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(String userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getUserProfilePicture() {
        return userProfilePicture;
    }

    public void setUserProfilePicture(String userProfilePicture) {
        this.userProfilePicture = userProfilePicture;
    }

    public String getCommentDate() {
        return commentDate;
    }

    public void setCommentDate(String commentDate) {
        this.commentDate = commentDate;
    }

    public String getCommentSuggestPrice() {
        return commentSuggestPrice;
    }

    public void setCommentSuggestPrice(String commentSuggestPrice) {
        this.commentSuggestPrice = commentSuggestPrice;
    }

    public String getCommentDescription() {
        return CommentDescription;
    }

    public void setCommentDescription(String commentDescription) {
        CommentDescription = commentDescription;
    }

    public CommentsList(String userID, String userName, String userProfilePicture, String commentDate, String commentSuggestPrice, String commentDescription) {
        this.userID = userID;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.userProfilePicture = userProfilePicture;
        this.commentDate = commentDate;
        this.commentSuggestPrice = commentSuggestPrice;
        CommentDescription = commentDescription;
    }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
  mDatabase.child("Posts").child("Books").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
final ArrayList<String> keysArray= new ArrayList<String>(); // if you want to store all the keys
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    String key = data.getKey(); //Here you can get all your keys from Books
                    keysArray.add(key);
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"database error",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: i want store post keyGenerated in post_Id in the BooksAdapter
so that when i click on the Post in recycler view   i send the id with Intent.putExtra